# Ошибка при попытке получить данные с uncplash.com. Неверный токен

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit, token, authenticationtoken

при попытке запросить данные с сайта [Unsplash](https://unsplash.com) выводится ошибка о недействительном токене. Я пытаюсь достать рандомную фотографию с сайта и вывести ее на экран телефона.

> {"errors":["OAuth error: The access token is invalid"]}
>   [image]

Код клиента

```
OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request original = chain.request();
                    Request request = original.newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("Authorization", "Client-ID " + ACCESS_KEY)
                            .method(original.method(), original.body())
                            .build();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            }
            );
```

Лог

> 08-17 20:22:25.729 7696-7696/? D/Unsplash: Url = https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random

Пробовал разные токены, не помогает. Что делать?

Код главной активности. Приложение обходит метод `onResponse()` и переходит сразу в `onFailure()`

```
NetworkService.getInstance()
            .getJSONApi()
            .getRandomPhoto()
            .enqueue(new Callback<Photo>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Photo> call, Response<Photo> response) {
            Photo photo = response.body();
            Picasso.get().load(photo.getUrls()
                    .getRegular())
                    .into(imageView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Photo> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "Url = " + call.request().url());
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Код Интерфейса

```
public interface UnsplashApi {
    @GET("photos/random")
    Call<Photo> getRandomPhoto();
}
```

Comment: А что там надо то

Comment: @Романыч обновил вопрос

Comment: А какие параметры указаны в апи? Скиньте где глянуть

Comment: @Романыч https://unsplash.com/documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что я нашел в доках нужно передавать вот так:

```
https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY
```

соответственно у вас не правильно составлен запрос.

```
public interface UnsplashApi {
@GET("photos/random")
Call<Photo> getRandomPhoto(
                      @Query("client_id") String API_KEY);
```

}

А в запросе

```
NetworkService.getInstance()
        .getJSONApi()
        .getRandomPhoto(ACCESS_KEY)
```

как то так примерно

Первая попавшаяся [гуглежка](http://fabcoding.com/creating-an-image-picker-using-unsplash-photos/)  дала результат. Быть может вас для начала стоило воспользоваться интернетом

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Теперь мне стыдно за свою невнимательность